# Не работает order_by при генерации dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Делаю так:

```
for i in Category.query.order_by(desc(Category.position)):
    print(i.name)
```

Получаю:

```
>>> Category3
>>> Category2
>>> Category1
```

Если же делаю так:

```
zxc = {c.name: c.position for c in Category.query.order_by(desc(Category.position))}
    print(zxc)
```

то получаю:

```
>>> {'Category1': 1, 'Category2': 2', 'Category3': 3}
```

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Словарь — штука по определению неупорядоченная, юзайте `OrderedDict` или что-нибудь как-нибудь ещё

Comment: Согласен.  from collections import OrderedDict

Answer (score 0):

В цикле вы выводите всё поочерёдно. Во 2 примере вы делаете словарь из значений, и только потом его выводите.
А вообще используйте:

```
ORDER BY Category DESC
```

Сортировать по спаданию.

Comment: Тогда нужно формировать словарь с учётом нужной последовательности ?

Comment: Вам я так понимаю нужно сортировать по спаданию?

Comment: Сортировка происходит нормально, с запросом в БД всё в порядке.
Проблема именно в том, что сам словарь хранит данные неупорядоченно.
OrderedDict же сортирует по ключу или значению, однако я ни в ключах, ни в значениях, не храню элемент, по которому нужно сортировать.
В идеале бы, сделать, чтобы словарь хранил последовательность изначально.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik: `OrderedDict()` НЕ сортирует по ключу или значению. Он в порядке ставки хранит (конкретные ключи и значения не играют роли).